# How to make a geoprocessing service return results in a specific spatial reference

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-10.2, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, geoprocessing-service

I have made a geoprocessing service which retrieves data from my enterprise geodatabase. My geometries are stored in wgs 84 srid (4326), but i need my data to be returned with a different spatial reference, since I want to use them in a graphics layer, and as I know graphics layer in not reprojected on the fly.

Comment: Can you edit the geoprocessing model itself? That would be the best way to do it.

Comment: @Devdatta Tengshe yes I can. I am the one implementing it. But   in that case I would prefer the the srid that I want my data to be convrted in, to be a parameter passed from my client. So  my service would return data that could conform to any spatial reference of any basemap.

Comment: you could try with project_management, but this is a bit risky with any type of projection, because the user would also need to specify the transformation when needed otherwise the projection will be inaccurate.

Answer (score 1):

Have you seen output spatial reference on the geoprocessing endpoint itself?  https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jsapi/geoprocessor-amd.html#outspatialreference
and  [Output spatial reference (coordinate system)](http://resources.arcgis.com/EN/HELP/MAIN/10.1/index.html#//0057000000m9000000)

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing it in `arcpy`, then I think you are looking for [Project (Data Management)](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00170000007m000000):

```
arcpy.Project_management (in_dataset, out_dataset, out_coor_system, {transform_method}, {in_coor_system})
```

For model based geoprocessing services, I think there is an alternative, but you might be able to just wrap this into one.